# Linear congruential generator testing full period

Tags: python, random, modulus

Write a program to demonstrate that for a linear congruential generator with modulus
 = 2
 and constant  = 1, in order to achieve the full period, the multiplier  must be
equal to 4 + 1. Consider  =5, 7, and 10; and  =2 and 9. You should also consider
two values of the multiplier that do not match this.

My problem with this is that I have the code to run this in Python.  The suggestions I have been given are

```
def lcg(modulus, a, c, seed):
    """Linear congruential generator."""
    while True:
        seed = (a * seed + c) % modulus
        yield seed
```

However, the problem does not mention the seed value, nor do I know how to tell if it will achieve a full period.  Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**What is the seed?**

The variable `seed` refers to the state of the RNG (Random-Number Generator).  You must have some sort of changeable state, even if it's the position in a file or true random numbers, or the RNG will return the same number on every call.

For a LCG, the seed is simply the most recent value.  You save that in a driver routine, or as some sort of internal status integer.  It's usually an optional parameter; you provide it on the first call to "seed", or begin the sequence.

**How to tell whether I get the full sequence?**

Since the LCG state is entirely described by the most recent value, it returns a constant cycle of values, repeating that cycle for as long as you use it.  To test this, you can simply start with a seed of 0 (any value will do), and then count how many iterations it takes to get that value again.

You can also determine the cycle length from the LCG parameters.  This is a research project for the student (start with Wikipedia).

Does that unblock your worries?